# Converting Json object to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

In a few posts here and also on other forums I have found this code quoted for turning a Json object into a DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

I can't get this to work.  It always throws a JsonSerializationException.  Am I missing something?

This is simple example to show error:

```
JObject query = new JObject();
JObject results = new JObject();

results.Add("Name", "Blue Umbrella");
results.Add("Price", 100);

query.Add("results", results);

DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(query.ToString(), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'd take a look at what the string value is that is produced by `query.ToString()` and compare that with the other examples that you've seen.

Comment: Why convert it to a data table? Why not convert to a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use something like:

```
JArray array = new JArray();

{
    JObject row = new JObject();

    row.Add("Name", "Blue Umbrella");
    row.Add("Price", 100);

    array.Add(row);
}

{
    JObject row = new JObject();

    row.Add("Name", "Green Umbrella");
    row.Add("Price", 200);

    array.Add(row);
}

DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(array.ToString());
```

The "container" must be a `JArray`.

The next time you have a similar problem, as suggested by @Dr. Wily's, simply try serializing something:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Price");

var row = dt.NewRow();
row["Name"] = "Blue Umbrella";
row["Price"] = 100;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

row = dt.NewRow();
row["Name"] = "Green Umbrella";
row["Price"] = 200;
dt.Rows.Add(row);

string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

and look at its format:

```
[{"Name":"Blue Umbrella","Price":"100"},{"Name":"Green Umbrella","Price":"200"}]
```

Comment: How to change this json string into Datatable C#      {
"apple.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"asdfgqwx.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"},
"microsoft.org":{"status":"unknown"},
"apple.org":{"status":"unknown"},
"microsoft.com":{"status":"regthroughothers","classkey":"domcno"},
"asdfgqwx.org":{"status":"unknown"}
}

Comment: @user3786581 I don't think you can: the key name canges, `"apple.com"` becomes `"asdfgqwx.com"` becomes `"microsoft.com"` It is more a `Dictionary<string, MyStatusClass>`. The question is complex enough that you should ask a full question.

Comment: Okay. Here is my full question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482580/how-to-convert-json-string-into-datatable-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp)